# comparing Unique and Concatenated values

Tags: postgresql

I'll just put this in layman's terms since I'm a complete noobie:

I have 2 tables A and B, both having 2 columns of interest named: employee_number and salary.

I want to do the 2 following operations/conditions simultaneously (please forgive the wrong function names.. this is just to present the problem) with a possible left join:

1.) A.unique(employee_number) exists in B.unique(employee_number) AND
    A.unique(salary) exists in B.unique(salary)

2.) A.numcat(employee_number,salary) <> B.numcat(employee_number,salary).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: numcat - I erroneously thought it's a concat function for numbers, just like textcat.

Comment: regarding duplicate employee_number values, yes and no. The same employee_numbers can be found multiple times in both tables. This is because Employees can get multiple paychecks from different departments, but there is no duplicate values of concat(employee_number, salary) in either table.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has row wise comparison (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-comparisons.html):

select * from A where (employee_number,salary) not in (select employee_number,salary from B)
or
select * from A where (employee_number,salary) in (select employee_number,salary from B)

I think, you want the first one (not in)